# RequireJS: Using "require" in the callback of another "require" doesn't load from CDN

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Is there any reason that calling `require` in the callback of a `require` function would load the 2nd / callback require from origin instead of from CDN?

Here's the code I have:

```
<script>
    var require = {
        baseUrl: 'http://my.cdn/assets/public/javascript/lib',
        paths: {
            app: '../app'
        }
    };
</script>
<script src='http://my.cdn/assets/public/javascript/lib/require.js'></script>

<script>
    require(['../commons'], function (common) {
        require(['app/somemodule']);
});
</script>
```

commons.js:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'assets/javascript/lib',
  paths: {
      app: '../app'
  },
  shim: {
    // shim configuration.
  }
});
```

When the page loads, require.js and commons.js are fetched from the baseUrl. However, somemodule is fetched from the page address. Moving the somemodule require out of the callback causes it to load from the baseUrl.

Why does the nested / callback require not use the basepath? Thinking that it's something to do with the callback function being passed to requirejs to execute in a context that is missing the requirejs configuration set up with the inline script....

Comment: Is there a call to `require.config` inside `commons`? If so, please add it to your question.

Comment: There's a call to requirejs.config, updating the question with it now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the requirejs baseUrl was being overridden in commons.js - thanks to @Louis for pointing me in the right direction.

Removed the `baseUrl` parameter from commons and all works as expected.